# Excel Find Cumulative Variance of summed YTD actual profit vs pre-filled monthly target

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find the Cumulative YTD $ and % variance of actual current month profit compared with pre-filled monthly target in Excel:

| B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Month | Monthly Target | YTD Actuals | Variance ($) | Variance (%) | **Cumulative Variance ($)** | **Cumulative Variance (%)** |
| January | $100,000 | $110,000 | $10,000 | 10% | $10,000 | 10% |
| February | $120,000 | $125,000 | $5,000 | 4% | $15,000 | 6.8% |
| March | $125,000 | $90,000 | ($35,000) | (28%) | ($20,000) | (5.8%) |
| April | $115,000 | $105,000 | ($10,000) | (8.7% |  |  |
| May | $120,000 | $125,000 | $5,000 | 4.2% |  |  |

Column C is already pre-filled for the whole year. I need columns G and H to calculate the cumulative YTD variance each month without columns E or F which is only included for explanation. Each month's variance, should calculate what the total YTD should be vs what it actually is. For instance, March Cumulative Variance ($) is Jan - March monthly target summed ($345,000) minus Jan - March YTD Actuals summed ($325,000). Difference YTD being -$20,000.

Is there a simpler way than cell formulas being:

- G2 =sum(C2-D2)
- G3 =sum(C2:C3)-(D2:D3)
- G4 =sum(C2:C4)-(D2:D4)

Where the same formula can apply to each cell but yield their respective results based on the month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you calculate the cumulative variance by cumulating the variances?

```
G2  =Sum(E$2:E2)
```

Then copy and paste down column G - the `$` will anchor the start of the range to row 2:

```
G13  =Sum(E$2:E13)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot simpler and yields same results.